# Show div using jQuery, .toggleSlide doesnt work?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a div section using .slideToggle(), but it doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
        <a href="#" class="add-sources">Add sources</a>

                <!-- Hide until Click -->
                <div class="add-sources-interaction" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="source-1">Sources</label>
                            <input type="text" name="source-1" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #1" id="source-1">
                            <input type="text" name="source-2" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #2" id="source-2">
                            <input type="text" name="source-3" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #3" id="source-3">
                        </div>
                </div>
</form>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.add-sources').click(function(){
    $('.add-sources-interaction').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

I get this error:

`Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6`

I'm using other jQuery functions throughout my application which seems to require the jQuery versions I'm importing.

I removed:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

.slideToggle() still doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

Complete files with `<script>` #1 and #3 replaced by `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` follow,

**master.blade.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('src/css/main.css') }}"> <!--Gets absolute path -->


    </head>
    <body>
        @include('includes.header')
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{ URL::to('src/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    @include('includes.message-block')
    <section class="row new-post">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <header> 
                <h3>What do you have to say?</h3>
            </header>

            <form action="{{ route('post.create') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Your title" id="title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="new-post" rows="15" placeholder="Your Post"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"> <!-- blade if statements which adds bootstrap class 'has-error' if field has error -->
                    <label for="category">Category</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Categories, separate using comma."> <!-- Request::old fetch old value from form -->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="type">Article type</label>
                    <select name="type" class="form-control" id="type">
                        <option value="News article">News article</option>
                        <option value="Opinion">Opinion</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="image">Upload image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="image">
                </div>

                <a href="#" class="add-sources">Add sources</a>

                <!-- Hide until Click -->
                <div class="add-sources-interaction" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="source-1">Sources</label>
                            <input type="text" name="source-1" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #1" id="source-1">
                            <input type="text" name="source-2" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #2" id="source-2">
                            <input type="text" name="source-3" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #3" id="source-3">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <br></br>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Post</button>



                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            </form>

        </div>
    </section>

    @include('includes.newsfeed')
@endsection
```

**app.js:**

```
var postId = 0;
var postBodyElement = null;

$('.post').find('.interaction').find('.edit').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    postBodyElement = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    var postBody = postBodyElement.textContent; // event is argument passed through, target find .post, childNodes[1] find index 1
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid']; //access data-postid element within dashboard


    $('#post-body').val(postBody); //Sets post-body textarea value to var postBody                  
    $('#edit-modal').modal(); // Calls modal function within jQuery
}); 

$('#modal-save').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({   //ajax function within jQuery, url and token gets specified within the dashboard.blade.php page.
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlEdit,
        data: { body:$('#post-body').val(), postId: postId, _token: token} //Data from textarea
    }) 
    .done(function (msg){
        $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']); //How is msg and postController return connected?
        $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
    });
});

$('.like').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null; //Checks if it's a like or dislike.

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {isLike: isLike, postId: postId, _token: token}
    })
    .done(function(){
        //Change the page when .ajax has men executed.
        event.target.innerText = isLike ? event.target.innerText == 'Like' ? 'You like this post' : 'Like' : event.target.innerText == 'Dislike' ? 'You don\'t like this post' : 'Dislike';

        //Make sure you can't dislike and like at the same time.
        if(isLike){
            event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Dislike';
        } else {
             event.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = 'Like';
        }
    });
});

/* Opens subcomment-interaction */

$('.subcomment').click(function(){
    $('.subcomment-interaction').show();
});


/* Opens add-sources-interaction */
$('.add-sources').click(function(){
    $('.add-sources-interaction').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Are you attempting to load multiple versions of jQuery on the same project? (1.12 and 3.1) Because that won't work...

Comment: Remove jQuery 1.12 and leave only 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question's code you have 4 `<script>` tags. remove no. 1 and 3. in their place add this version of jquery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a working snippet :

```js
$('.add-sources').click(function(){
    $('.add-sources-interaction').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <a href="#" class="add-sources">Add sources</a>

                <!-- Hide until Click -->
                <div class="add-sources-interaction" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="source-1">Sources</label>
                            <input type="text" name="source-1" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #1" id="source-1">
                            <input type="text" name="source-2" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #2" id="source-2">
                            <input type="text" name="source-3" class="form-control" placeholder="Source #3" id="source-3">
                        </div>
                </div>
</form>


        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont understand. it is working in the snippet in my answer.  are you deleting `jquery-1.12.0` and `jquery/3.1.0` which are first and third script in your code

Comment: Yeah, that's weird, it still doesn't work when remove <script> #1 and #3. I did remove big parts of the code in the original post which I believed to be irrelevant to make it easy to read. 

I'll edit the post and post the complete code.

Comment: I'll added the complete code, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: code all looks good just make sure that there are no errors in the files you are including `@include('includes.newsfeed')` and `@endsection`. and if still gives you error then try this microsoft cdn `<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` and if still not working then try downloading the juery-2.1.1 and including it instead of using a cdn

Comment: Seems like it had something to do with cache or session.
It didn't work yesterday, today I re-opened without making any changes to the code and it worked.

Comment: Nice. I'm happy for you